# (Senior) High school student resume for part-time tutoring position

Tags: resume

I am applying for a part-time tutoring job offered on Craigslist. 
This is a description of the job:

> *We are now actively accepting resumes, and we encourage you to fill out an application and take an entrance exam at our office today. We are
>   particularly interested in hiring a tutor who specializes in
>   upper-level Science (Chemistry, Biology, Physics) and Math (Algebra 2,
>   Geometry, Calculus).
>
> Tutoring/teaching experience is preferred but not required. Willing to train. >Working hours are flexible and can accommodate your schedule. Students vary >from elementary to adult age.*

I'm very new to applying for jobs... According to the first sentence, I need to fill an application, but they are also asking for a resume. Do I send my resume when I submit my application? When do I send a resume?

***Edited above to be more specific to the job that I am applying to ***

**Do high school students need to put an education?**
If so, is this appropriate?

Education:  Podunk High School, class of 2014 (4.4 GPA)

(For senior high school students) 
If a student is an incoming freshman at a college/university, i.e. paid enrollment deposit, should the student list the college/university he/she will be attending? If so, what is the appropriate way to write it?

**Where do high school students input clubs/organizations/competitions**
Would HS students only list down their clubs/organizations?
When should HS students describe their clubs/events/competitions and other extracurriculars?

**Do high schools students need references?**

**Is it beneficial to HS students to tell employers that they  are willing to work for a lower wage?**
Would this be placed on the resume or said during the job interview?

**Lastly, how to make HS resume stand out for tutoring position?**

Comment: Hey PodunkHS, and welcome to [workplace.se]! Since you got an answer to your question, I am going to put it on hold since it doesn't really fit the guidelines in our [help]. A much better question (if you'd like to ask it separately, or edit this one) would be something like, *"What should I do if I need clarification on the application process for a part-time job?"* and explain the confusion with the process. After you've confirmed what's needed for the application, then asking specific questions about what is appropriate to put in the resume/application would be good. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do high school students need to put an education?

You are going for a tutoring job.  This means you have to list the best education you have - in this case, your high school education. Be sure to include your GPA, if it's a good one. Parents derive a tremendous amount of reassurance from tutors being excellent, successful students and they are more than willing to pay if they think the tutors' academic success will rub off on their kids. So, play their game and again, list the GPA if it's a good one :) Feel free to list the big name universities that you've been admitted to, as part of demonstrating how successful you are academically. If you've been admitted to UCLA, but you are choosing to attend community college for the first two years and transfer, put up "admitted to UCLA" in your resume.

> Where do high school students input clubs/organizations/competitions?

You put "ACTIVITIES" right after the "EDUCATION" category listing. Be sure to mention any academic competition you participated in, any tutoring you performed, any awards you got. Since you are going for a tutoring job, make sure that you mention any activity that requires excellent communication skills.

> Do high schools students need references?

You don't need to mention anything about references in your resume. Wait until they ask for references, then volunteer say your math, chemistry, physics, etc. teachers and their contact info :) Since it seems that you are applying to a tutoring service, they'll probably provide forms for your teachers to fill out and instructions on how to bring back the forms to the turing service. Bottom line is: don't worry about the references business.You'll take care of it when the time comes.

> Is it beneficial to HS students to tell employers that they are willing to work for a lower wage?

Get out of here!  Don't you think that the legal hourly minimum wage is low enough? When it comes to getting paid, individuals with a high school education are the lowest of the low, except for those who don't have a high school education. Don't say anything. Let them make you the offer.

> Lastly, how to make HS resume stand out for tutoring position?

Education. Academic awards. Academic competitions. Community activities - you're telling them you are used to interacting with all kinds of people.  Anything that indicates that you have good communication skills.

At the interview, let it come across that you like people and that you know how to deal with them - I like people in general, but knowing how to deal with jerks and miserable individuals is an essential life skill :) Hey, you have to take the good with the bad :)

Good luck to you, and feel free to ask about anything that's unclear to you :)

Comment: To those assuming that the pay is minimum wage, the job offers $10 an hour, lol.

Thank you for the advice.  I have not been admitted to big names schools, sadly.  I am attending the University of Alabama in the fall.  Would this be a strength or a weakness if I inputted it into my resume?

Comment: Mention the big name universities you've been admitted to. Then if you want, list that you are attending the University of Alabama for financial reasons. They'll understand and sympathize :) FYI, the world is a big place and $10 is nothing in our NYC neck of the woods :) Fact is, $10 is good for a high school student but you can't support yourself on it as an adult, so let's not get carried away that $10 is more than minimum wage :)

Answer (score 1):

> Do high school students need to put an education?

Yes. People who are hiring tutors need to know your level of education to know what subjects you are qualified to tutor. This should be common sense.

> Where do high school students input clubs/organizations/competitions

There are numerous on-line resume templates that tell you how to format your resume. Your high school should also have a guidance counsellor office that has brochures on how to write a resume. A little effort on your part here is needed.

> Do high schools students need references?

If this is *required* it will be stated in the job description. They may still ask you for them at the interview, even if it is not explicitly stated. Teachers who can vouch for your knowledge on the subjects you want to tutor is  always a good thing to have

> Is it beneficial to HS students to tell employers that they are
>   willing to work for a lower wage?

Absolutely not. Why are you short-changing yourself, if you think that you are qualified tutor? Also, remember that minimum wage laws exist for a reason. It is illegal to offer/accept employment for less.

> Lastly, how to make HS resume stand out for tutoring position?

This is the art of resume writing that nobody but you can do. Only you know what you have to offer and what skill set you can bring to the job. Your career counsellor and resume writing books can help you in how to think about your qualities, but ultimately it is up to you to evaluate yourself and highlight your skills.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding the lower wage, the starting pay is $10 an hour, no way near minimum wage.  I asked if it was beneficial in the sense that I was more likely to be hired because I have no tutoring experience.

Comment: @PodunkHS The word you're looking for is "nowhere near" not "no way near". (Yes, grammar and spelling count.) Second of all, think about what argument you are trying to make and how it is reflecting upon how you are perceiving your skills. "Hire me because I will take less money!" That does not reflect positively on you. You need a better argument than "I'm cheap".

Answer (score 0):

The key to your employability is in this sentence:

> Students vary from elementary to adult age.

In short, some of the students would be middle school or high school freshmen, in such a situation a graduating high school student is an appropriate tutor.

Your resume should focus on the relevant topics you're interested in tutoring.  If this is algebra, for instance, you would want to emphasize what courses you've taken (including calculus) and whether you've done anything in the 'real world' with such education.  An example might be writing some kind of computer program to plot graphs, particularly with spreadsheet data. Something you could do if you haven't already is a regression analysis using spreadsheet data points.

Your references would be your instructors: whoever was teaching algebra, geometry, calculus, chemistry, etc.  Working for someone doing data entry doesn't count, however creating reports for someone using a departmental database does.